# sorting a ListField in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a model in mongoengine defined like this:

```
class Task(Document):

    name = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    frequency = IntField(required=True)
    quantity = IntField()
    units = StringField()
    events = ListField(DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now))
```

How can I get the latest `event`? I've tried the following to no success:

```
def latest(self):
    return self.events.sort()[-1]
```

Instead of returning the `events` sorted `sort` returns `None`

Comment: You could just use the Mongoengine SortedListField instead of ListField, [here is the doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SortedListField)

Then you could simply `return self.events` or its reverse if you wish as well

Comment: @SreenadhTC this sounds like a good solution. If you want to write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the Mongoengine SortedListField instead of ListField, [here is the doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SortedListField)

Then you could simply `return self.events` or its reverse if you wish as well